# Java application console prompt

Tags: java, console, stdin

I have written the following Java code to show a prompt and read some commands on the command line:

```
try(Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(">> ");
        System.out.flush();
        System.out.println(keyboard.nextLine());
    }
}
```

The prompt ('>> ') is not shown.
Anyway, if I enter text on the command line and hit enter, the prompt is shown before the output of println.
Is there any way I can force the prompt to be shown correctly? My understanding was that using flush was enough.

This is what I see in the console right now if I run a test

```
test
>> test
this
>> this
again
>> again
```

As you can see, the prompt is show after entering text read by keyboard.nextLine().

Comment: I think it will help if you add the current output and the expected output to the question.

Comment: Well, on the first iteration there is no output. After entering the command and reading a line of text I see the prompt and the output coming from println.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all strings are arrays of characters with a '\0' attached to the end (also called a null terminating character). For example, if I had a `string str = "hello";`, in reality `str` is really an array of 6 characters:
`['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0']`.

`flush()` simply removes the '\0' after the string `">> "`. The main issue here is that you had `Scanner` read in the input before prompting the user. To prompt before asking, move the `println()` statement on top.

```
System.out.println(">> "); //assuming this is your prompt
try(Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)) {
while (true) {
      //some code
   }
}
```

Your other option is to change `.nextline();` to `.next();`. The difference between the 2 are

> - nextLine(): Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.
> - next(): Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

For more references on `Scanner` functions you can read them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: Putting it before doesn't change the outcome. Thanks.

Comment: Also replacing nextLine with next doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am running the console application inside IntelliJ, while it looks like if I run the jar from the terminal everything is ok. As a result, it looks like IntelliJ output window is messing up something.